# sugarcrm programmatically hiding module menu

Tags: sugarcrm

I know there is a way to hide module menu from `Admin -> Display Modules and Subpanels`.
Is there any way to do the same from the code.

Particularly I need to hide my custom module: cm_items. This way customers could access this module items from the other referenced custom module.

I'm using the PRO edition of SugarCRM Versión 6.5.11 (Build 8754)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the module isn't listed in the global array $moduleList and it shouldn't be available to be added.

Comment: If I remove the module from array $moduleList, will be it available from REST API? I'm using REST API to insert these items.

Comment: It works in partial. It removes the menu, but when I enter to the parent module, and go to the item, the top menu appears again, I click there and still see the list of items. any idea?

Comment: @jmetric after I removed the module from $moduleList, I found some strange behavior. The menu some times appears again on the site. Does it related to some template caching?

Answer (score 3):

In your modules/cm_items/ directory you should be able to drop in an empty Menu.php file. If that doesn't work try resetting the $module_menu array in that file:

```
$module_menu = array();
```

Comment: There were already Menu.php, I added on the end `$module_menu = array()`, also I tried to add the same to `/custom/extension/modules/cm_items/Ext/Menus/CustomMenu.php`. But menu still there. The only what was disappeared is sub-menu of the module (Create new item, View of item and Import)

Answer (score 1):

just comment the line in custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/en_us.lang.ext.php file

```
$app_list_strings['moduleList']['cm_items'] = 'items';
```

Comment: It's not working, actually the correct place to comment the line is in: `custom/Extension/application/Ext/Language/..` if no the file from your location will be regenerated after Admin -> Repair.